# Why ReactJS navigation return me an error?

Tags: reactjs

I learn reactJS, and now i try to get a navigation.

But i have this error : 'reactNavigation.useTheme is not a function, reactNavigation.useTheme is undefined'

My app.js :

```
    import React from 'react'
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <Navigation/>
    )
  }
}
```

And my navigation.js :

```
    import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack'
import Search from '../Components/Search';
import FilmDetail from '../Components/FilmDetail';

const SearchStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Search: {
    screen: Search,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Rechercher'
    }
  },
  FilmDetail: {
    screen: FilmDetail
  }
})
```

export default createAppContainer(SearchStackNavigator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found, that was here :

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack'
```

I juste need to call 'react-navigation' and that work